# How to display error message using passport in view

Tags: node.js

I want to display error or succuss message during authentication using passport,my code in passport.js is:

```
var passport = require('passport');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy,
    User = require(process.cwd() + '/app/models/user');
module.exports = function() {
    passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
            usernamelocal: 'userid',
            passwordlocal: 'password'
        },
        function(username, password, done) {
            User.findOne({
                userid: username
            }, function(err, user) {

                if (err)
                    return done(err);

                if (!user) {
                    console.log("*************user name error");
                    this.message = "user error";

                    return done(null, false, {
                        message: 'unknown user'
                    });
                }
                if (user.deleted) {
                    console.log("user deleted error");
                    return done(null, false, {
                        message: 'unknown user'
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    ));
}
```

Comment: In addition to this configuration which you've specified above, you normally have a place where you specify certain requests require authentication by checking if the `req.isAuthenticated()`.  Do you have that code too?  Also, to display a message to the user you would normally have a view, do you have code for the view?